# Express V in terms of P for equation of state

Tags: polynomials

This is the equation of state

$$
\left(P + \frac{n^2*a}{V^2}\right)(V-nb)=nRT
$$

where a, b, n, R, T are constants.

The actual question is to calculate $\frac{dV}{dP}$, so in order to do that I'm first trying to solve the above function for V in terms of P.

What I did so far:

1. simplify by eliminating brackets
2. move terms with V to the left and without to the right

What I end up with is a 3rd power polynomial

$$PV^3-(nbP+nRT)V^2 + n^2aV = n^3ab$$

and I don't know how to proceed. Usually I factor out the variable in question and divide by the other factor, but that isn't applicable this time.

Is my whole approach wrong? Please help!

Comment: This belongs on math.se or possibly physics.se But that approach isn't going to work. Just look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B(P+%2B+n%5E2+a%2FV%5E2)+(V+-+n+b)+%3D%3D+n+R+T%2C+V%2C+Reals%5D

Comment: allright, so that approach is unfeasible. I guess at least I can move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \left(p+\frac{an^2}{V^2} \right)(V-nb) &= nRT \\
  \left(p+\frac{an^2}{V^2} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial V}(V-nb)+
  (V-nb) \frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(p+\frac{an^2}{V^2} \right) &=
  \frac{\partial}{\partial V} (nRT) \\
  \left(p+\frac{an^2}{V^2} \right)+(V-nb)
  \left[ \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \right)_{T}-
  \frac{2an^2}{V^3} \right] &= 0 \\
  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \right)_{T} &=
  \frac{2an^2}{V^3}-\frac{nRT}{(V-nb)^2} \\
  \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_{T} &=
  \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_{T}} \\
  &= \frac{V^3(V-nb)^2}{2an^2(V-nb)^2-nRTV^3}
\end{align*}

Comment: This looks like what I want, but could you elaborate what your reasoning is? I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not make any error, here is what I think you are waiting for. First  set the constants

```
SetAttributes[a, Constant]
SetAttributes[n, Constant]
SetAttributes[R, Constant]
SetAttributes[b, Constant]
SetAttributes[T, Constant]

eq := (P[V] + ( a n^2)/V^2) (V - n b) - n R T == 0
```

Then Dt[eq, V] is the derivative of the lhs of the equation according  to V

```
Solve[Dt[eq, V], P'[V]]

Dt[eq[V], V]
```

is the derivative or eq[V]  according to V. Have a look at it. Then

```
sol = Solve[Dt[eq[V], V], P'[V]]
```

is your answer. You can go further in substituting its value to P that is

```
FullSimplify[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. P[V] -> Solve[ (P + ( a n^2)/V^2) (V - n b) - n R T == 0 , P][[1, 1, 2]]]
```

Comment: If you do not want to write P[V], but only P, you will be oblige to substitute Dt[P,V] to P'[V]